# libsc-a2xx.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix

Tags: android

I get this message in logcat:

```
libsc-a2xx.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
```

Does anyone know what it mean?

Comment: This is by now a well-known warning message.  As documented at the link, if the mentioned library is yours you can rebuild with a newer NDK.  But if it is a system library there is nothing you can do but wait for the device to be upgraded - it is, after all, only a warning and not an error.